# Get data from multiple spinners generated dynamically in linearLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher, dynamic-view

I am trying to add a dynamic view inside my LinearLayout and **trying to implement something like to catch every spinner value corresponding to time**. Can anyone over here can guide me that how it can be done. **I am trying it but it's not working as there can be infinite rows with spinners based on the click on the "ADD FILED" button**. I need to collect value from each spinner and need to create an array then.

**Here is my code** :

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private LinearLayout parentLinearLayout;
    private EditText mEditText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        parentLinearLayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_linear_layout);
    }
    public void onAddField(View v) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_item, null);
        final EditText text1 = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text);
        final EditText text2 = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text2);
        final EditText text3 = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text3);

        text1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() > 0) {
                    text3.setText(text1.getText().toString());
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+s.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        text2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() > 0) {
                    int val = Integer.parseInt(text1.getText().toString());
                    int val2 = Integer.parseInt(text2.getText().toString());
                    if(val2>val)
                    {

                    }else{
                        int finalval=val-val2;
                        text3.setText(""+finalval);
                    }


                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+s.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        text3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() > 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+s.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });


       parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount());
    }
    public void onDelete(View v) {
        parentLinearLayout.removeView((View) v.getParent());
    }
    public void onGetField(View v){
        int count = parentLinearLayout.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View row = parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
            EditText textOut = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text);
            String data = textOut.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(this,""+data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**Dynamic view XML** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:inputType="phone"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number_edit_text2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:inputType="phone"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number_edit_text3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:inputType="phone"/>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/type_spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:entries="@array/types"
        android:gravity="right" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        android:onClick="onDelete"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Main XML** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/parent_linear_layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_field_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="#555"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onAddField"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:text="Add Field"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/get_field_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="#555"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onGetField"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:text="Get Field"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please let me know your valuable suggestions on this. I have been stuck since the last day.

Here is the attached image and in the image you can see that the 3rd edit text is empty which I need to fill by using text watcher on 1st two edit-text like 2(first edit-text)-1(second edit-text) = 1 (on thrid edit-text).

[image]

Regards

**Below is the second approach using Recyclerview**:

**MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int position=0;
    List<Container_Add_model> main_modelList = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView recyclerView_container;
    TextView Tv_add_container;
    Container_Add_Adapter rvAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        recyclerView_container = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_container);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView_container.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        Tv_add_container = findViewById(R.id.Tv_add_container);


        rvAdapter = new Container_Add_Adapter(MainActivity.this, main_modelList,this, new Container_Add_Adapter.Onclick() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(Container_Add_model model, int pos) {

            }
        });
        recyclerView_container.setAdapter(rvAdapter);


        Tv_add_container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                rvAdapter.addClick();

            }
        });

    }
```

**Adapter Class** :

```
public class Container_Add_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Container_Add_Adapter.RvViewHolder> {
    Activity context;
    List<Container_Add_model> models;
    Onclick onclick;
    View view;
    EditTextAdded editTextAdded;
    private int container_number_pending, container_number_taken, container_number_given;

    public Container_Add_Adapter(Activity context, List<Container_Add_model> models,EditTextAdded editTextAdded, Onclick onclick) {
        this.context = context;
        this.models = models;
        this.editTextAdded = editTextAdded;
        this.onclick = onclick;
    }

    @Override
    public Container_Add_Adapter.RvViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        view = inflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.container_item, parent, false);
        RvViewHolder rvViewHolder = new RvViewHolder(view);
        return rvViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final Container_Add_Adapter.RvViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Container_Add_model model = models.get(position);

        holder.Edttxt_given_container.setText(models.get(position).container_given+"");
        holder.Edttxt_given_container.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() > 0) {
                    // models.get(position).container_given = Integer.valueOf(s.toString());
                }
            }
        });


        holder.Edttxt_taken_container.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() != 0) {
                    if (!holder.Edttxt_given_container.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

                        container_number_given = Integer.parseInt(holder.Edttxt_given_container.getText().toString());
                        int number = container_number_given + container_number_pending;

                        int input_num = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
                        if (number >= input_num) {
                            container_number_taken = Integer.parseInt(holder.Edttxt_taken_container.getText().toString());
                            int final_num = number - container_number_taken;
                            holder.Edttxt_Pending_container.setText("" + final_num);
                        } else {
                            holder.Edttxt_taken_container.setText("");
                        }
                    } else {
                        holder.Edttxt_taken_container.setText("");
                    }

                } else {
                    if (!holder.Edttxt_given_container.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        container_number_given = Integer.parseInt(holder.Edttxt_given_container.getText().toString());
                        if (container_number_given > 0) {
                            int finalnum = container_number_given + container_number_pending;
                            holder.Edttxt_Pending_container.setText("" + finalnum);
                        } else {
                            holder.Edttxt_Pending_container.setText("" + container_number_pending);
                        }
                    } else {
                        holder.Edttxt_Pending_container.setText("" + container_number_pending);
                    }

                }
            }
        });


        holder.Iv_delete_container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                models.remove(position);
                notifyItemChanged(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged (position, models.size());
            }
        });
    }


    public void addClick(){
        Container_Add_model container_main_model = new Container_Add_model();
        container_main_model.setContainer_given(0);
        container_main_model.setContainer_pending(0);
        container_main_model.setContainer_taken(0);
        container_main_model.setContainer_id(models.size());
        container_main_model.setContainer_name("");

        models.add(container_main_model);
        //notifyDataSetChanged(models);
        notifyItemInserted(models.size() + 1);

    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return models.size();
    }

    public interface Onclick {
        void onEvent(Container_Add_model model, int pos);
    }

    public class RvViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView Tv_container_type;
        EditText Edttxt_given_container, Edttxt_taken_container, Edttxt_Pending_container;
        LinearLayout llItem;
        ImageView Iv_delete_container;

        public RvViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Tv_container_type = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Tv_container_type);
            Iv_delete_container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Iv_delete_container);
            Edttxt_given_container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Edttxt_given_container);
            Edttxt_Pending_container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Edttxt_Pending_container);
            Edttxt_taken_container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Edttxt_taken_container);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983122/i-want-to-implement-textwatcher-for-dynamically-generated-edittexts-and-want-to .....like this?

Comment: @notTdar Hey my case is different please have a look at the screenshot

Comment: @user2028 where is the textWatcher implementation code?

Comment: I did not understand the purpose of the work. but, if you want to save the change of the whole list of `EditText`, then why don't you use RecyclerView?

Comment: @hassanmoradnezhad  I tried with that too but was getting position problems. Let me post that too here if you could help me in that way.

Comment: @user2028 Yes, I would be happy if I could help

Comment: @hassanmoradnezhad please check now

Comment: 1st, would you please share your problem with the position? 2nd, there are 3 `EditText` in your layout. do you want to listen to whole 3 `EditText` changes or just a specific one?  3rd, share your model class too, please

Comment: it's basically a container management process in which I am getting input from a customer that how much containers have been given to you and how much you returned. So in short the first one is the number of given container and 2nd one is the taken based on these 2 third will show how much pending.  So as the containers can be of different type so it can be added as new fields below and at the end I will be sending all values in array to server.

Comment: while removing the layout i am getting crash java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected.

Comment: @user2028 
`notifyItemRemoved(position);`
`notifyItemRangeChanged(position, models.size());`
instead of
`notifyItemChanged(position);`
`notifyItemRangeChanged (position, models.size());`

Comment: This thing rest the values which lies below the deleted item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is what you were missing** :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private LinearLayout parentLinearLayout;
    private ArrayList<> mList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        parentLinearLayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_linear_layout);
    }
    public void onAddField(View v) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_item, null);
        final EditText text1 = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text);
        final EditText text2 = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text2);
        final EditText text3 = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text3);
        final Spinner mSpinner = (Spinner) rowView.findViewById(R.id.type_spinner);

        mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
               String selectedDiv = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+selectedDiv, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {
                // can leave this empty
            }
        });

        text1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() > 0) {
                    text3.setText(text1.getText().toString());
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+s.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        text2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() > 0) {
                    int val = Integer.parseInt(text1.getText().toString());
                    int val2 = Integer.parseInt(text2.getText().toString());
                    if(val2>val)
                    {

                    }else{
                        int finalval=val-val2;
                        text3.setText(""+finalval);
                    }


                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+s.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        text3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() > 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+s.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });


       parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount());
    }
    public void onDelete(View v) {
        parentLinearLayout.removeView((View) v.getParent());

    }
    public void onGetField(View v){
        mList = new ArrayList<>();
        int count = parentLinearLayout.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View row = parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
            EditText textOut = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text);
            EditText textOut2 = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text2);
            EditText textOut3 = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.number_edit_text3);
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner)row.findViewById(R.id.type_spinner);
            mList.add(new DataList( textOut.getText().toString(),
                    textOut2.getText().toString()
                    , textOut3.getText().toString(),spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()
            ));

        }
    }
}
```

**Datalist Model** :

```
public class DataList {

    public String given;

    public String taken;

    public String pending;

    public String spinnerItemSelected;

    public DataList(String given, String taken, String pending, String spinnerItemSelected) {
        this.given = given;
        this.taken = taken;
        this.pending = pending;
        this.spinnerItemSelected = spinnerItemSelected;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your String array to ArrayList and pass it to Adapter and use below code or change below code with your String[].

You need to implement Filterable to your Adapter class and Override getFilter()

```
public class ListFilterActivity extends ListActivity {

    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> mOriginalValues;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, getModel());
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        EditText filterEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filterText);

        // Add Text Change Listener to EditText
        filterEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // Call back the Adapter with current character to Filter
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    }

    private List<String> getModel() {
        list.add("Linux");
        list.add("Windows7");
        list.add("Suse");
        list.add("Eclipse");
        list.add("Ubuntu");
        list.add("Solaris");
        list.add("Android");
        list.add("iPhone");
        list.add("Windows XP");
        return list;
    }
}

// Adapter Class
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    List<String> arrayList;
    List<String> mOriginalValues; // Original Values
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<String> arrayList) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.textview);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textView.setText(arrayList.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

                arrayList = (List<String>) results.values; // has the filtered values
                notifyDataSetChanged();  // notifies the data with new filtered values
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
                List<String> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<String>();

                if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                    mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<String>(arrayList); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
                }

                /********
                *
                *  If constraint(CharSequence that is received) is null returns the mOriginalValues(Original) values
                *  else does the Filtering and returns FilteredArrList(Filtered)
                *
                ********/
                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                    // set the Original result to return
                    results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                    results.values = mOriginalValues;
                } else {
                    constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalValues.size(); i++) {
                        String data = mOriginalValues.get(i);
                        if (data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())) {
                            FilteredArrList.add(data);
                        }
                    }
                    // set the Filtered result to return
                    results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                    results.values = FilteredArrList;
                }
                return results;
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}
```